# Replace all occurrences that match regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression that searches for a string that contains `'.00.'` or `'.11.'` as follows:

```
.*\.(00|11)\..*
```

What I would like to do is replace all occurrences that match the pattern with `'X00X'` or `'X11X'`. For example, the string `'.00..0..11.'` would result in `'X00X.0.X11X'`.

I was looking into the Python re.sub method and am unsure of how to do this effectively. The returned match object only matches on the first occurrence and therefore doesn't work well. Any advice? Should I just be using a string replace for this task? Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`re.sub()` (docs for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)) does replace all matches it finds, but your use of `.*` may have caused the regex to match too much (even other occurences of `.00.` etc.). Simply do:

```
In [2]: re.sub(r"\.(00|11)\.", r"X\1X", ".00..0..11.")
Out[2]: 'X00X.0.X11X'
```

Note that patterns cannot overlap:

```
In [3]: re.sub(r"\.(00|11)\.", r"X\1X", ".00.11.")
Out[3]: 'X00X11.'
```

Comment: Does re.sub use search and not match? I was using .* since I assumed it used match.

Comment: In Python, `match` searches for a match at the start of a string, it does not require a full string match. `re.sub` finds all non-overlapping sequences matching the pattern and replaces them.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand: from the docs _"Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl"_: how is this "replacing all matches it finds"?

Comment: @gented: the regex engine works its way through the string from left to right. As soon as it finds a match, it replaces it and moves on. Therefore,

Comment: if your string is „aaaa“ and you replace „aa“ with „bb“, you get „bbbb“ instead of „bbbbbb“ even though there are three (overlapping) instances of „aa“ in the string.