# How to edit a string inside a list withPython

Tags: python, string, list

If I have a list, each item is a string-type item. Let's say inside every item there is a specific set of words that I want to remove. How can I do that?

This is my own approach that didn't work.

```
        for row in new_basket:
            if "\n" in item:
                item = item.replace("\n", "")
            if "pattern" in row:
                item = item.replace("pattern", "")
            if "potato" in row:
                item = item.replace("potato", "")
            if "another text I don't want" in row:
                item = item.replace("another text I don't want", "")
```

Example input:

['Name: Mark's potato', 'Date of Birth: 11/11/1111', 'Details: Red']

Desired output:
['Mark's potato', '11/11/1111', 'Red']

Comment: Can you provide the sample input and expect output?

Comment: I can come up with an example yes. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: You're calling `item` too early . You should be searching `row`. E.g. `NameError: name 'item' is not defined`

Comment: @af3ld I don't understand.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156956/replace-all-occurrences-that-match-regular-expression

Comment: based on your code, the variable `row` is the individual item in iterated list. In the second line you're asking if `"\n"` exists in `item` which at this time is undeclared. Then when potato is in `row`, you try to preform a string function on `item`, which still may or may not be declared yet

Comment: @af3ld The iterated list contains a lot of rows of e.g potatoes data. I wanted to write an example of a row.

Comment: @quiteLost24 - are you sure your input is correct?  It seems to me a dictionary, than a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this situation using `regex`, is simple!

```
import re

pattern = ["Name: Mark's potato", "Date of Birth: 11/11/1111", "Details: Red"]

for i in range(len(pattern)):
    pattern[i] = re.sub('.*:\s*|(\r\n|\r|\n)', '', pattern[i])

print(pattern)
```

Comment: This is very nice. The only thing missing from here is stripping of new lines.

Comment: Also I'd use `.*:\s*` instead of `.*:.` for the prefix to match only spaces and not remove any actual characters.

Comment: @MYousefi it's reasonable!

Answer (score 0):

Someone will probably have a better way to do this, but the following should get you there:

`mylist = ['test', 'cat', 'teeth', 'bite']`

`mylist = [s.replace('t','') for s in mylist if 't' in s]`

`mylist = [s.replace('c','') for s in mylist if 'c' in s]`

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered your question hope I understood what you meant

```
list_ = ["house", "potato", "pattern"]
def list_replacer(original, replacement):
    if original in list_:
        i = list_.index(original)
        list_.pop(i)
        list_.insert(i, replacement)
        print(list_)
    
    else:
        print('The operation is impossible')
    
    
list_replacer("house", "city")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
my_list = ["Name: Mark's potato", "Date of Birth: 11/11/1111", "Details: Red"]    
keywords = ['\n', '\r', '\r\n'] # Common new line encoding
# Put other keywords into the list
# Note that if all of the strings look like with 'Keyword: Value' you can just append '^.*:\s*' in a lazy regex otherwise 
keywords.append('Name: ')
keywords.append('Date of Birth: ')
keywords.append('Details: ')

def replace(my_list, keywords):
    regex_pattern = '|'.join(keywords)
    return [re.sub(regex_pattern, '', s) for s in my_list]
```

This function works for one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your inputs are similar to this example, you can have your desired output with:

```
your_list = ["Name: Mark's potato", "Date of Birth: 11/11/1111", "Details: Red"]

your_desired_output = [li[1].strip() for li in [item.split(':') for item in your_list]]
```